# issue creating sliders with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z277ZUHNnnE&feature=youtu.be&t=4m49s) from helpingdev, but have come up against a brick wall - I've followed every step so far as i can tell and have the interface working - however when i run the page the image doesn't change, it simply stays on the first one.

the video is over three years old, so I'm guessing something in the syntax just need's to be changed - i just can't figure out what even with chrome dev tools.

Thanks for your help.

Here's the html, css, and js for the page:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Slider example.</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/slider.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="slider">
            <img id="1" src="../images/tromso.jpg">
            <img id="2" src="../images/fjord.jpg">
            <img id="3" src="../images/tromso_aerial.jpg">
            <img id="4" src="../images/sognefjord.jpg">
         </div>

         <a href="#" class="left">Previous</a>
         <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>

      </div>

      <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/slider.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 30px auto;
}

#slider > img {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   float: left;
   display: none;
}

a {
   padding: 5px 10px;
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
   margin-top: 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #666;
}

a.left {
   float: left;
}

a.right {
   float: right;
}
```

js:

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300);
   startSlider();

});

function startSlider(){
   count = $("#slider > img").length;

   loop = setInterval(function(){

      if(sliderNext > count){
         sliderNext = 1;
         sliderInt = 1;

      }

      $("slider > img").fadeOut(300);
      $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

      sliderInt = sliderNext;
      sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

   },3000);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 
  `$("slider > img").fadeOut(300);`

Should be

`$("#slider > img").fadeOut(300);`

You missed a `#` in front of `slider`

Also remove the code `loop =` you are assigning a function to the `loop` variable but never executing it. So what you need is to run it rather than assigning it.  Removing the assignment will execute that block of code.

Comment: Thanks, is there some way you know of that I can debug my code better to look for small errors like this? Or should I just stick to meticulously scanning it?

Comment: You can use the browser developer console.. it logs all the errors. Also you can use a `debugger` keyword in your code and just keep open your dev tools and when ever the script encounters this keyword it stops for you to debug.. you can use F10 to debug and see what each line of code produces .. Also F11 helps in block code execution, F8 skip to end or untill next debug point

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into using the debugger keyword next time I encounter something like this.

Comment: @Laurens Happy coding